# I am trying to download a book that I need for class (I'm the teacher) for offline viewing but I am running into a lot of problems

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to use the selenium python library to open the url, and use the browsers builtin save as to save it as a xht file.  It works if I do it by hand but I am having problems automating it.  I want to add this to a larger program but for now I just need it to work for a singular URL.  I have tried everything that I can think of or find online but no luck so far.  The browser opens and loads the link but it looks like the browser is not responding to the keys presses.  I have done this in a few different ways including the selenium.webdriver.common.keys and pyautogui.

First, I tried scraping the file and saving it as an XHTML, but except for the structure, the file was empty. Since the website is dynamically generated, I used Insomnia to send a GET request to the page, and it opened up perfectly in Insomnia. However, when I copied the request to Python, the file was empty again, except for the structure. I then tried downloading the file received from Insomnia, which Insomnia displayed perfectly. But once again, it was empty, except for the structure.

I realized that I could save the page the way I wanted by clicking "File," then "Save As," and saving the whole page as XHT. Now, I am trying to automate that process, but I am running into a lot of trouble. I want to add this to another scraping program that I made, so I can open the table of contents of the book and have it download the whole book for me. I don't want to take a screenshot or print as a PDF since I still want the text to remain text, so I can copy and paste from the book if necessary.

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pyautogui

# List of URLs for each page of the ebook
page_urls = [
    'https://ebooks.boost-learning.co.uk/4Pim8vo0ePBcsNbNvor5qBJlswtEnDHR/FNovrUipJO_ex-bo/9781398372870-1.1.1/EPUB/fxl/page008.xhtml',
    # Add more page URLs here
]

# Initialize the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Loop through each page URL
for url in page_urls:
    # Open the URL in the webdriver
    driver.get(url)

    # Wait for the page to load
    time.sleep(5)

    # Press the Ctrl+S keyboard shortcut to save the page
    pyautogui.press('ctrl+s')

    # Wait for the save dialog to appear
    time.sleep(5)

    # Press the Enter key to save the page
    pyautogui.press('enter')

# Close the webdriver
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, the pyautogui.hotkey simulates the CTRL+S

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pyautogui

# List of URLs for each page of the ebook
page_urls = [
    'https://ebooks.boost-learning.co.uk/4Pim8vo0ePBcsNbNvor5qBJlswtEnDHR/FNovrUipJO_ex-bo/9781398372870-1.1.1/EPUB/fxl/page008.xhtml',
    # Add more page URLs here
]

# Initialize the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Loop through each page URL
for url in page_urls:
    # Open the URL in the webdriver
    driver.get(url)
        
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 's')
    pyautogui.write('filename')
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    
    pyautogui.sleep(3)
# Close the webdriver
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code lies in the line.

```
pyautogui.press('ctrl+s')
```

you have to properly input ctrl+s action in multiple steps as follows.

```
pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
pyautogui.keyDown('s')
pyautogui.keyUp('s')
pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
```

.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pyautogui

# List of URLs for each page of the ebook
page_urls = [
    'https://ebooks.boost-learning.co.uk/4Pim8vo0ePBcsNbNvor5qBJlswtEnDHR/FNovrUipJO_ex-bo/9781398372870-1.1.1/EPUB/fxl/page008.xhtml',
    # Add more page URLs here
]

# Initialize the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Loop through each page URL
for url in page_urls:
    # Open the URL in the webdriver
    driver.get(url)

    # Wait for the page to load
    time.sleep(1)

    # Press the Ctrl+S keyboard shortcut to save the page
    pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
    pyautogui.keyDown('s')
    pyautogui.keyUp('s')
    pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')

    # Wait for the save dialog to appear
    time.sleep(1)
    # Press the Enter key to save the page
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    # wait extra time before closing driver.
    time.sleep(0.1)

# Close the webdriver
driver.quit()
```